# LowProfileImageLoader get OutOfMemoryException Windows Phone

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, out-of-memory, loadimage

I am using LowProfileImageLoader  to load images async without block UI.

You can get it from link: [LowProfileImageLoader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2011/03/03/quot-your-feedback-is-important-to-us-please-stay-on-the-line-quot-improving-windows-phone-7-application-performance-is-even-easier-with-these-lowprofileimageloader-and-deferredloadlistbox-updates.aspx)

Everything is OK if DataSource of List has many different links.

**But now, I want to test with DataSource with all same URL so In file TwitterService.cs, I edit followed:**

```
private static void HandleGetFollowersResponse(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var state = (GetFollowersState)result.AsyncState;
//#if DEBUG
            try
            {
//#endif
                //using (var response = state.Request.EndGetResponse(result))
                //{
                //    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                //    {
                //        var document = XDocument.Load(stream);
                //        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                //        {
                //            foreach (var user in document.Element("users_list").Element("users").Elements("user"))
                //            {
                //                state.Collection.Add(new TwitterUser(user.Element("screen_name").Value, new Uri(user.Element("profile_image_url").Value)));
                //            }
                //        });
                //        var nextCursor = document.Element("users_list").Element("next_cursor").Value;
                //        if ("0" == nextCursor)
                //        {
                //            // Load completed
                //            if (null != state.OnFollowersLoaded)
                //            {
                //                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => state.OnFollowersLoaded());
                //            }
                //        }
                //        else
                //        {
                //            // Load the next set
                //            MakeGetFollowersRequest(state.ScreenName, nextCursor, state.Collection, state.OnFollowersLoaded);
                //        }
                //    }
                //}

                throw new WebException();
//#if DEBUG
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                 //No network access; create some fake users for debugging purposes
                for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                {
                    state.Collection.Add(new TwitterUser("Fake User " + i, new Uri("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-O-6vxSiyvbk/UClib6CiR0I/AAAAAAAAQaI/5Fr1dI-kQBI/s1600/Flowers+beauty+desktop+wallpapers.+(1).jpg")));
                }
                if (null != state.OnFollowersLoaded)
                {
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => state.OnFollowersLoaded());
                }
            }
//#endif
        }
```

**It will create dataSource of List with 200 item that has same URL to test.**

***In LowProfileImageLoader.cs, I log the currentUsedMemory of app:***

```
private static void WorkerThreadProc(object unused)
    {
            // Process pending completions
                    if (0 < pendingCompletions.Count)
                    {
                        // Get the Dispatcher and process everything that needs to happen on the UI thread in one batch
                        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {

                            while (0 < pendingCompletions.Count)
                            {

                                Logger.printUsedMemory();
                                }
                            }
                        }

    }
```

Logger.printUsedMemory() is helper function to help me log current used memory of my app.
Nothing edit anymore in code.

But when run my app, the result is strange:
**I get OutOfMemoryException.**

***Text log in Output windows (used memory in bytes) bellow:***

```
 Used memory: 21966848
 Used memory: 25051136
 Used memory: 28442624
 Used memory: 32673792
 Used memory: 35512320
 Used memory: 39079936
 Used memory: 43364352
 Used memory: 46571520
 Used memory: 49815552
 Used memory: 53497856
 Used memory: 52514816
 Used memory: 55902208
 Used memory: 60452864
 Used memory: 62001152
 Used memory: 65503232 ~ 65.5mb
 Used memory: 69005312 ~ 69mb
```

Text log show that **after loading image memory increase ~ 3mb** although **image size (from URL) only 120kb.**

Why does the OutofMemoryException throws ?
Why garbage collection not call and my memory increased steady ?

Any help is very apprepriate.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> image memory increase ~ 3mb although image size (from URL) only 120kb

When the image is displayed, it has to be decoded from JPEG so it is normal that it takes more memory. Try to convert the image to BMP with Paint to see it.

> Why does the OutofMemoryException throws ?

You probably go above the 90 MB limit

> Why garbage collection not call and my memory increased steady ?

Check out this Nokia article: [Consider replacing long lists with images with ListBox replacements that use Data Virtualization](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Best_practice_tips_for_delivering_apps_to_Windows_Phone_with_256_MB#Tip_.238_-_Consider_replacing_long_lists_with_images_with_ListBox_replacements_that_use_Data_Virtualization)

Comment: Thank you. But I have another question: Why is everything is OK if DataSource of List has different links ? I mean that dataSource haved different links so memory also increase with less size memory (often < 1mb and I sure that image size of that URL ~ image size of URL in case Using same URL);